# Handlebar não funcionando no Firefox

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Eu estou tentando usar template para criar células em uma tabela porem o codigo só funciona no google chrome, alguem sabe porque?

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Handlebars.js tutorial</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <section id="content"></section>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script id="example-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        </table>
        <table >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>team name</th>
                <th>position</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            {{#each array1}}
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>{{name}}</td>
                <td>{{age}}</td>
              </tr>
              {{/each}}
            </tbody>
          </table>    

    </script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var $orders = $('#orders');
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];

function parse(){
  $.ajax({
    headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': '69e49cf35c7346fcb819f023cf0b98d4' },
    url: 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/398/leagueTable',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
  }).done(function(response) {
    var regex = /.*?$/;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      array1.push({name:response.standing[i].teamName, age:response.standing[i].position,email:1});
      console.log(array1[i]);
}
var a = {
  array1
};
var theTemplateScript = $("#example-template").html();
var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);
var theCompiledHtml = theTemplate(a);
$(document.body).append(theCompiledHtml);
});

}



(function(){
  parse();


})();
```

Comment: Qual o erro que ocorre?